# Loading text files into socioboard for auto posting

Tags: asp.net, social-networking

I have been looking to enter the text files into socioboard, so that it reads the url's from the text file and automate the process of posting those url's on social websites.

So I need to know, how could I upload that text file into socioboard and to automate the process of posting.

Please Help!

Comment: Looks like the publishing tab has a feature to upload a file of messages/tweets. Also how is this a programming question? Are you stuck somewhere programming this feature in socioboard or you are looking for a method to upload a file?

Comment: Sumit thanks for your reply, Yes I am looking for a feature in socioboard to upload a file and the url's in that file being auto posted to social networks via socioboard.